# best server to upload sqlite database

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite, upload

i built an iphone app which access sqlite database, i wanna upload the database on server.
Does the code of connecting and access the database will change ?

And what the best server to upload Sqlite database for iphone apps ?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the SQLite homepage: http://www.sqlite.org/

SQLite is a software library that implements a self-contained, **serverless**, ...

SQLite databases are designed to be only used locally, usually inside a single application. They are not **meant to be uploaded** in any way. (Obviously, you can however export the data, and upload the data dump.)

Comment: What you mean by dump ? Even I am looking to upload the comp database to the server.Can you please let me know how should I manage it ?

Comment: See https://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html and look for the `.dump` command. That is how to export SQLite database as text for transfer to another server.

Comment: Thanks Anony.One more thing how can I run the .dump command from iPhone app to create the database text file ? And seems .dump file is used to restore the complete db, but in my case I have to update the database on the server in my case.Do you think it would be much appropriate.

Comment: I do not have an iPhone. I hate Apple for its technology lock-in approach, and I would never buy Apple products. SQLite is a local only approach. If you want to update a server database, you will have to do your own protocol to transmit the updates to the server. SQLite is not client-server.